# The derivative of matrice's multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives

Given $F=A^TA$, with $A$ is a $m\times n$ matrix. Then what is the derivative w.r.t. $A$ ?

I know when $A$ is a $m\times 1$ vector, the derivative is $$\frac{\partial F}{\partial A} = 2A$$.

Does this equation still hold when A is extended to $m\times n$ matrix?

Answer (score 2):

$F(A+H) = (A+H)^{t}(A+H) = (A^t + H^t)(A+H)=A^t A + A^tH + H^t A + H^t H.$

So $$F(A+H) - F(A) = A^t H + H A^t + O(||H||^2).$$
So the derivative is the map
$$
H \mapsto A^t H + H A^t.
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.**

$F$ can be written by function composition of the functions:

$$R: A \longmapsto A^{T}$$ and
$$S: (A,B) \longmapsto A.B$$ The first one is linear, so its derivative is itself. The second one is bilinear and its derivative is $S^\prime(A,B)(h,k)=A.h+k.B$

At the end, you have to use the chain rule to compute the derivative of the composition of both.